# Coaxial cable length degrades connection performance?

Tags: networking, router, performance, cable

The coaxial cable provided by my ISP was a tad short for my needs. I bought a new one about 5m long (I only need around 3m) and noticed a substantial loss in connection speed and performance.

The technician assured me I had to use the original case provided, which got me thinking.

With all the wiring running inside my reasonably old building, up to the 3rd floor where I live, it's hard to believe the coax cable I used was causing the problem.

Why is the coaxial cable so bad at degrading the signal? Is it safe to believe the wiring the runs through my building is so much better than a new coaxial cable?

**Update with the original cable specs:**

This is what's written on the original cable:

```
3214 AAW EN 60966-2-3 CE RoHS Class A+
```

Comment: There are different types of coax, did you use the same rated one?

Comment: From what I understood the rating is related to the shielding. The one I used has a shielding rate of 135db (and 75ohm).

Comment: Your line of thinking is accurate, an additional 5 meters (16 feet) is NOT, the source of your performance issues. What is the rating of the original cable?

Comment: There are many types of coaxial cable, and you need to use one that is rated for your application. It would help if you would tell what reads on the old and new cable. They both could have same impedance and shielding of 135 dB but if the new cable is not of suitable type then it isn't.

Comment: I've added the specs of the original cable. I guess the relevant part is Class A+?